# looping through dataframe add rows to column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataset that i read in:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('.../data.xlsx')
```

the content looks like this:

```
Out[57]: 
        Block    Concentration          Name      value
          1            100           GlcNAc2      321
          1            100           GlcNAc2      139
          1            100           GlcNAc2      202
          1            33            GlcNAc2      86
          1            33            GlcNAc2      194
          1            33            GlcNAc2      452
          1            100            BCC         345
          1            100            BCC         6
          1            100            BCC         34
          1            33             BCC         11
          1            33             BCC         53
          1            33             BCC         87
          1            0       Print buffer       127
          1            0       Print buffer       55
          1            0       Print buffer       67


 ...     ...            ...               ...        ...               ...

         24             0       Print buffer      -9968
         24             0       Print buffer      -4526
         24             0       Print buffer      14246
```

1. i want to for each Block and Name , add three '0' concentrations and add the 3 'print buffer' values from that Block to those three new '0' concentrations.

   ```
       Out[57]: 
       Block    Concentration          Name      value
         1            0             GlcNAc2       127
         1            0             GlcNAc2       55
         1            0             GlcNAc2       67
         1            100           GlcNAc2      321
         1            100           GlcNAc2      139
         1            100           GlcNAc2      202
         1            33            GlcNAc2      86
         1            33            GlcNAc2      194
         1            33            GlcNAc2      452
         1            0              BCC         127
         1            0              BCC         55
         1            0              BCC         67
         1            100            BCC         345
         1            100            BCC         6
         1            100            BCC         34
         1            33             BCC         11
         1            33             BCC         53
         1            33             BCC         87
         1            0       Print buffer       127
         1            0       Print buffer       55
         1            0       Print buffer       67
   ```

   ...     ...            ...               ...        ...               ...

   ```
        24             0       Print buffer      -9968
        24             0       Print buffer      -4526
        24             0       Print buffer      14246
   ```
2. compute the average of the 3 'print buffer' and subtract that by every value from the same Block.

   desired output:

   ```
      Out[57]: 
       Block    Concentration          Name      value         newvalue
         1            0             GlcNAc2      127            127-mean(127+55+67)
         1            0             GlcNAc2      55             55 -mean(127+55+67)
         1            0             GlcNAc2      67             67-mean(127+55+67)
         1            100           GlcNAc2      321            321-mean(127+55+67)
         1            100           GlcNAc2      139             139-mean(127+55+67)
         1            100           GlcNAc2      202            ....
         1            33            GlcNAc2      86
         1            33            GlcNAc2      194
         1            33            GlcNAc2      452
         1            0             BCC          127
         1            0             BCC          55
         1            0             BCC          67
         1            100           BCC          345
         1            100           BCC          6
         1            100           BCC          34
         1            33            BCC          11
         1            33            BCC          53
         1            33            BCC          87
         1            0        Print buffer      127
         1            0        Print buffer      55
         1            0        Print buffer      67

   ...     ...            ...               ...        ...               ...

        24             0       Print buffer      -9968
        24             0       Print buffer      -4526
        24             0       Print buffer      14246
   ```

   ## pseudo code:

   ```
   for each block
      for each Name
       add concentration '0' three times
       append the three values of 'print buffer' to the three '0' concentrations 
       newvalue = value - average(three print buffer)
   ```

Comment: my new post @Andy Hayden :)

Comment: @Parfait please see my new post here

Comment: you've got a couple of problems here. the first involves repopulating your dataframe from a subset. the other, more computational problem involved not `for` loops, but `groupby` and `transform` (or `apply`?) operations. I recommend splitting this up into two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [groupby apply functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to dataset. The first function averages the values only for 'Print Buffer' using `mean()`, leaving the others in Block zero. And then the second function maximizes the `meanvalue`. Finally, simply create `newvalue` as arithmetic difference:

```
def add_mean_value(mgrp): 
    mgrp['meanvalue'] = mgrp[mgrp['Name'] == 'Print buffer']['value'].mean()    
    return mgrp
data = data.groupby(['Block', 'Concentration', 'Name']).apply(add_mean_value)    

def max_sum_value(mgrp):    
    mgrp['meanvalue'] = mgrp['meanvalue'].max()    
    return mgrp
data = data.groupby(['Block']).apply(max_sum_value)

data['newvalue'] = data['value'] - data['meanvalue']
print(data)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    Block  Concentration          Name  value  meanvalue  newvalue
0       1            100       GlcNAc2    321         83       238
1       1            100       GlcNAc2    139         83        56
2       1            100       GlcNAc2    202         83       119
3       1             33       GlcNAc2     86         83         3
4       1             33       GlcNAc2    194         83       111
5       1             33       GlcNAc2    452         83       369
6       1            100           BCC    345         83       262
7       1            100           BCC      6         83       -77
8       1            100           BCC     34         83       -49
9       1             33           BCC     11         83       -72
10      1             33           BCC     53         83       -30
11      1             33           BCC     87         83         4
12      1              0  Print buffer    127         83        44
13      1              0  Print buffer     55         83       -28
14      1              0  Print buffer     67         83       -16
```

Comment: thank you this is helpful. can you help me understand better? the first part of sumvalue is summing up the 'print buffer' values for each block. what is the max_sum_value part? does it return only the max value ? where is the part of taking average of the 3 'print buffer' and subtracting that from every value? thanks!

Comment: after trial and error i finally figured it out! to take average: `sgrp['sumvalue'] = sgrp[sgrp['Name'] == 'Print buffer']['value'].mean()` and the rest is pretty much the same. thanks again @Parfait  for your help!

Comment: Apologies, I viewed your desired result and did not see average taken. Yes, use `mean()` instead of `sum()` although you mention it in the text.

Comment: thank you, i indeed forgot to put the average in my desired output. i have edited for future references.